# How to tackle when init/constructor of an object depends on another instance of the same class?

Tags: python, oop, language-agnostic, builder

I am working with a stochastic model, and ended up in a situation where the instantiation of a model order n depends on a model of lower order, in order to assess the priors correctly. In other words, initial values of the  instance variables are dependent on another instance of the same class.

A direct consequence of this is that the `__init__` method will require another instance of the same class, which will obviously end up calling itself... It feels really shaky to get into something like that, even if it can be made to work.

Just to visualize the idea:

```
def __init__(self, order, other, ...):
  if(other.order != order -1):
    raise ValueError(...) # <- complain loudly

  self.A = other.trainedA
  self.B = other.trainedB
  ...
  self.train()
```

I have been reading a bit about different [creation pattern designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) and intuitively I feel the Builder pattern sounds like something appropriate in this case. Is it an overkill, considering that I will most likely call upon the Builder once per execution?

What is the simplest/most intuitive way to approach this problem?

Comment: Would a base case work? Like "I'm the first object, I don't have to call anybody" then then next and following take the other route? Or would that not apply in your circumstance?

Comment: When a constructor depends on another instance of the same class, **you pass the other instance as an argument.** That other instance could have been created using the same constructor -- but on a different layer in the call stack. Constructors can be called more than once. Well-written constructors can be called at multiple layers in the call stack.

Comment: @AndyThomas could you please give an example to illustrate your point?